# Lucene 4.10.3 numeric date range query does not return expected results

Tags: java, lucene, range, numeric

Here is a simple test code that creates three documents with one date field each, then does date range search, expected to find two documents, but none is returned (environment: Lucene 4.10.3, Java 1.7.0_55, Windows 7). Could someone have a look and tell me if there's anything I'm doing wrong. Slav

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;


public class LuceneTest {
    private static final java.text.SimpleDateFormat DATE_PARSER = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    private static final String INDEX_PATH = "/tmp/lucene";

    private static Date parseDate(String dateSt) {
        synchronized(DATE_PARSER) {
            try {
                return DATE_PARSER.parse(dateSt);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Create an index
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_PATH));
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_2, analyzer);
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);

            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new LongField("BirthDate", parseDate("1989/11/01 10:11:12").getTime(), Field.Store.YES));
            writer.addDocument(doc);

            doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new LongField("BirthDate", parseDate("1973/03/02 13:14:15").getTime(), Field.Store.YES));
            writer.addDocument(doc);

            doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new LongField("BirthDate", parseDate("1969/01/31 16:17:18").getTime(), Field.Store.YES));
            writer.addDocument(doc);

            writer.close();

            //Now do searching

            IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_PATH)));
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

            Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("BirthDate", 4, parseDate("1969/01/20 00:00:00").getTime(),
                parseDate("1973/03/03 00:00:00").getTime(), true, true);
            System.out.println("query: " + query);

            TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, null, 100);
            ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = results.scoreDocs;
            int hits = scoreDocs.length;
            int count = results.totalHits;

            for(int i = 0; i < hits; i++) {
                doc = searcher.doc(scoreDocs[i].doc);
                String value = doc.get("BirthDate");
                System.out.println(new Date(Long.parseLong(value)));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is suited to codereview.stack not stackoverflow.

Comment: I was not aware of the existence of codereview.stack. Please leave my question here and next time I will use codereview.stack for similar issues.

Comment: The question's title says "does not return expected results".  This sort of question is categorically off-topic on [codereview.se].  Do **not** migrate questions that will be closed at the destination site.  Just vote to close if it's off-topic here.

Comment: @Fluffeh No, this does not belong on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run the test locally and found out, that the problem is in **precisionStep** - you didn't index properly for precisionStep = 4.

So, you could remove **precisionStep** in query at all or index documents properly, like this

```
final FieldType type = new FieldType();
            type.setNumericPrecisionStep(4);
            type.setStored(true);
            type.setIndexed(true);
            type.setNumericType(FieldType.NumericType.LONG);
            doc.add(new LongField("BirthDate", parseDate("1969/01/31 16:17:18").getTime(), type));
```

Comment: Please note that I use date's millisecond value (getTime() in the code above) as LongField's value rather than a Date object, which, I believe, is correct. Besides I'm using Lucene, not SOLR, so I cannot use SOLR's TrieDateField.

Comment: i missed that, update answer with real working solution

Comment: Mysterion, you're absolutely right, it is the different precision step used for indexing and then searching, thanks so much. I think that the Lucene team should update the LongField documentation where it says that the default precision step is 4, but in fact it is 16 in the code!